# how to debug nifi in IDEA

Tags: apache-nifi

can I debug nifi in IntelliJ IDEA?  as I only see in http://nifi.apache.org/quickstart.html about how to build nifi project and run with shell command, no information about how to run or debug in IDEA such as IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’ll want to uncomment the remote debugging line in your `conf/bootstrap.conf` file, start NiFi normally using `./bin/nifi.sh start`, and then use your IntelliJ debugger to connect to that port (I believe 8000 by default).